# Delete database entry using codeigniter ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this script

```
  <script>
$('a[name=deleteButton]').on('click', function () {
    arr=[];
    var arr = $("input[name='post[]']:checked").map(function() { 
            return this.value; 
          }).get();
          var content = $(this).parents('tr').find('.key').html();
          alert(content);
          $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/partner/app/deleteRowUsingApiKey/delete",
            cache: false,               
            data:{empId : content},
            success: function(response){                        
            try{        
                if(response){
                    parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                            alert(response.responseText);
                }                   

            }catch(e) {     
                alert('Exception while request..');
            }       
            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
         });


});

</script>
```

This is the controller for delete

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class DeleteRowUsingApiKey extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function delete(){           
        $empId =  $this->input->post('empId');      


        $status = "true";

        echo $status;

    }
}
```

This is the view

```
<tbody id="dashboard_table_body">
                            <?php if($admin_activation_status!='disabled' && $tot!=0)
                                    { $i=0; foreach ($connct_data as $row): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type='checkbox' name='post[]' value="<?php echo ++$i; ?>"></td>
                                <td><?php echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime($row['connct_CreationTime']));?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['connct_serviceName'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['connct_websiteUrl'];?></td>
                                <td class="key"><?php echo $row['connct_passKey'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['responseURL'];?></td>
                                <td><a name="deleteButton" href=""><i class="icon-remove text-danger"></i></a></td>
                                <!-- <td align='center' width='30'><a data-toggle='modal' href='#' ><i class='icon-remove text-danger'></i></a></td> -->
                            </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; } ?>
                        </tbody>
```

I am able to alert  variabe content,and the value of content is what I want to pass to the controller.But I am not able to communicate with the controller.Its not returning "true".

Im always getting 'Error while request' instead if the getting into if 'true' condition.

Is what I am doing is wrong.Is there any error in my code.Please help me fix this.

Thank you

Comment: try `if(response==="true"){` or try `($.trim(response)==="true")`

Comment: @user790454 No its still the same :(

Comment: try to `echo "1";` instead of true and check `if(response=="1")`

Comment: @user790454 No I still don't get it

Comment: You should return json data, which is more compliant. Something like return json_encode(array('statut' => TRUE)); and use datatype: 'json' in your Ajax call.

Comment: are you able to alert the data

Answer (score 0):

The method you are following is right. Once check your config/routes.php (whether you gave

correct path to the controller).

```
**In the controller:**

return true;

if(response){ } [is correct method in ajax]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data:'empId=' + content
```

should be

```
data: {empId: content}
```

this would send the data from js to server correctly

If you need more variables, then you should do like:

```
data: {empId: content, nameofVar2: valueOfVar2, nameOfVar3: valueOfVar3}
```

and then in controller just put:

```
$empId = $this->input->post('empId');
$nameofVar2 = $this->input->post('nameofVar2');
$nameofVar3 = $this->input->post('nameofVar3');
etc...
```

You should also json encode your return value in your controller:

```
echo json_encode($status);
```

and explicity set what datatype to return in your jQuery (so your absolutely sure whats expected as return value)

It should therefore be something like this in your jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://localhost/partner/app/deleteRowUsingApiKey/delete",
    cache: false,               
    data: {empId: content},
    dataType: 'json'
```

If it does not work, you can try:

```
error: function(ts){                      
                alert(ts.responseText);
            }
```

and see what the actual response is in your error.

**UPDATE**

I would try this:

I have this script

```
  <script>
$('a[name=deleteButton]').on('click', function () {
    arr=[];
    var arr = $("input[name='post[]']:checked").map(function() { 
            return this.value; 
          }).get();
          var content = $(this).parents('tr').find('.key').html();
          alert(content);
          $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/partner/app/deleteRowUsingApiKey/delete",
            cache: false,               
            data:{empId : content},
                    dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){                        
                alert('success function');
                    alert('respone from success function=' + response);
            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
         });


});

</script>
```

This is the controller for delete

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class DeleteRowUsingApiKey extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function delete(){           
        $empId =  $this->input->post('empId');      


        $status = "true";

        echo json_encode($status);

    }
}
```

Comment: Put dataType: json (row between data and success) in your jQuery and echo json_encode($status) in your controller.

Comment: Its still not working..When I checked the network tab in the console.I see that the POST status is cancelled.

Comment: Are you able to access the http://localhost/partner/app/deleteRowUsingApiKey/delete directly in your browser?

Comment: Yes.I am able to access it directly

Comment: What if you try to remove your try/catch block in the success-callback?